# Was there a word which meant roughly the same thing as "nerd" or "geek" does today?

Tags: classical-latin, medieval-latin, word-request

...That is, a word meaning someone with deep and specialized knowledge, and could be used either as a badge of pride:

> I'm a *huge* Linux nerd. I helped reoptimize some of the photonal decalcifiers for Intel CPUs.

...or a mark of shame:

> Ugh, you're such a nerd. Stop going on about your kernel!

(Those aren't the best examples, but I think they get the point across)

I'm looking for something from Classical or Medieval Latin, but if there's a neologism with a similar meaning, I'd be interested to know.

The context is a person mildly swearing at another person under their breath after they geek out about arcane tech, then the other person turning around and saying something along the lines of, "I sure am a nerd!" except with a few more words that you didn't know unicorns could say.

Comment: You tagged your question "classical/medieval Latin" but mention "tech." Are you looking for a cultural equivalent from that period or for a term for the current phenomenon?

Comment: Also, since it's bound to come up: https://xkcd.com/747/

Comment: @brianpck The cultural equivalent.

Comment: The sociological side just doesn't match up between our culture and theirs. This is one of the reasons that we know so little about Greco-Roman practical technology -- the kind of people who knew about water wheels, tanning, or metallurgy were slaves or plebeian laborers. The kind of people whose ideas are recorded by history are aristocrats who wouldn't have dirtied their hands with such matters. It's the complete cultural opposite of the Steve Wozniak/Elon Musk thing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Perhaps *graeculus*, often translated as Greekling?

It refers to Greeks who held positions of some import in Roman society due to their education and higher learning yet were considered too Greek to actually be considered proper Romans and, therefore, part of Roman society.  It was also used to mock those Romans who exhibited a taste for Greek language, learning and customs, most (in)famously, of Hadrian in the *Historia Augusta* but also of Claudius in the *Apocolocyntosis* (see section 5).

The diminutive suggests a pejorative, as does its use in context (for example, the *graeculus esuriens* in Juvenal, *Satires*, 3.78 or almost anytime Cicero uses it!).  The animosity inherent in the term seems to lie in the resentment of the erudition and cleverness of the Greek.  This is perplexing as Greek literacy was considered cultured and elegant among Roman elite.  Indeed, Cicero seems to use *graeculus* to mock Verres’ **lack** of authentic Greek learning (*Against Verres*, speech 2, book IV.127 – quite funny in its scathing sarcasm so I include a link: [Against Verres](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0012:text=Ver.:actio=2:book=4:section=127&highlight=graeculus)).  It has also been debated whether the use of *graeculus* to label Hadrian was a compliment or an insult.

Nevertheless, I don’t know if someone would lay claim to the label *graeculus* as a matter of pride.  Perhaps for a successful, well-educated Greek in Rome, appropriating the term ironically as a marker of his Greekness could be an act of self-affirmation.  Macrobius (who was possibly Greek himself) seems to use *graeculus* in an almost affectionate way.  See the *Saturnalia* VI.26, for instance, when a guest exclaims “εὖγε, graeculus noster!/Well done, our little Greek!” after a very erudite exposition of the nervous system without any apparent malice, and also at II.31.

Thus, *graeculus* could perhaps encapsulate the idea of someone with great erudition and skill but on the outskirts of society.  Further, its use as a pejorative or a compliment seems to lie in the eyes of the beholder (so to speak).  Of course, it is also a racial epithet so perhaps not quite what you’re after.  Even so, I thought it an interesting possibility so persevered with the research!

Comment: Welcome to the site and thank you for the interesting answer!

Comment: I think I like this the best: it's a great cultural parallel!

Comment: The other words are great for general put-downs as nerd was back in the day, but only this one I think really captures the cultural parallel.

Answer (score 7):

In his [Conversational Latin for Oral Proficiency](https://books.google.com/books?id=UOcRPumgVTsC&pg=PA260&lpg=PA260) (with which I am otherwise completely unfamiliar), John C. Traupman proposes [*inconcinnus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dinconcinnus), which is admittedly rare but has classical attestations. Lewis & Short glosses it as:

> inelegant, awkward, absurd

I would also cautiously advance [*ineptus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dineptus) as a possibility:

> unsuitable, impertinent, improper, tasteless, senseless, silly, pedantic, absurd, inept, without tact

Both words figure in Cicero's definition of an *ineptus*, in which he paints a picture of someone with no knowledge of social norms who wants to show off in a verbose way:

> qui aut tempus quid postulet non videt aut plura loquitur aut se ostentat aut eorum, quibuscum est, vel dignitatis vel commodi rationem non habet aut denique in aliquo genere aut **inconcinnus** aut multus est, is **ineptus** esse dicitur. (Cic. *de Orat.* 2.17)

(N.B.: *multus* here means "prolix"--I learned something new today!)

Both words are obviously pejorative in a way that modern-day "geek" or "nerd" are not necessarily. They emphasize the *lack* of a certain kind of knowledge rather than excellence in another kind. Honestly, though, the "nerd" indicates such a localized cultural phenomenon that it's notoriously difficult/impossible to translate: see [this Language Log post](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4505) for an enlightening discussion of attempts to find an equivalent for the word in Sinitic languages, for instance.

Comment: Ooh, I like this answer -- but being an *ineptus* or *inconcinnus* doesn't seem like something that could be seen as both an insult and praise, which is basically the whole thing I'm trying to get at.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Bear in mind that for many of us, when we were kids, nerd was definitely not praise, nor was geek, dork, and dweeb. It'd be like Roman kids going around saying, "Tam stultus sum!" Especially when you consider the etymology.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer you're right. I don't think "praise" is the right word -- it's more of an insulting word intentionally repurposed to mean something good to the insulted people, as they decided not to shy away from but accept and be proud of their label.

Comment: For what it's worth, I find a lot of Traupman highly suspect. The stuff in chapter 12—everyday locutions—is great, but the rest is a crap shoot.

Answer (score 7):

Coming at this from the opposite direction, the first word I think of is *artifex* (*-icis*, m/f). It refers to a person who is highly skilled and knowledgeable about a specific topic, but not necessarily in a good way. An *artifex* is capable of twisting and controlling and manipulating something, whether it be marble and paint or the mood of a crowd.

Here's a positive example from *Aeneid* 1.455:

> **artificumque** manus inter se operumque laborem
> miratur, videt Iliacas ex ordine pugnas...
>
> He sees the battles of Troy all in order, and marvels at the skill of the **crafters** and the effort of their works...

But it was also an epithet of Odysseus, for example, when Sinon is explaining how he was chosen as a sacrifice (2.125):

> hic Ithacus vatem magno Calchanta tumultu
> protrahit in medios; quae sint ea numina divum
> flagitat. et mihi iam multi crudele canebant
> **artificis** scelus, et taciti ventura videbant.
>
> Here Odysseus brought out the seer Calchas among them, amid great commotion; he demanded to know from him what the will of the Gods might be. And already many people were cruelly predicting **that schemer's** wickedness, and were foreseeing what was about to come.

I hesitate to call it a real translation of "nerd", since it doesn't imply anything about social awkwardness—quite the opposite, in fact. But it's a word implying specialized skill or knowledge, which can either be a compliment or an insult depending on context.

Comment: In an ecumenical spirit, how 'bout *artifex inconcinnus* :)

Answer (score 3):

In episode 8 I think of Legio XIII, Luke Ranierus, definitely one of the best Latin speakers in the world today, referred to himself as a nerd and he used the word 'umbratico' which L&S defines as an effeminate person, as well as one who is fond of the shade.  The word was only used 8 times up until 200AD according to packhum.  For those words that describe personality, it is very tough to figure out what they mean.  Just imagine if there was a nuclear war and many of records were destroyed and suppose that the word 'tacky' only appeared 8 times in our corpus, would you be able to figure out what it meant?

Comment: *Umbraticola* seems to be the word for an effeminate man. *Umbraticus*, on the other hand, does not seem to have that particular meaning, but seems to refer to bookish types who stay indoors.

Comment: Well, the word is only used 8 times in the packhum corpus.  Could you tell me what sentence(s) you're looking at that leads you to believe this? https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=umbratic

Comment: I wasn't looking at PHI, just Lewis and Short.

Comment: You have to look at the actual Latin texts.  Just because L&S says x does not mean that x is true.

Comment: This is the answer I would have given. I find the others, while creative, unsatisfactory.

Comment: Do you mean that 'umbraticola' or 'umbratico' is how you would translate 'nerd'.